# Can you still get a transcendence victory if the enemy built a mind flower first?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

How do the mechanics for the transcendence victory work?   I am in the middle of a long game, and in a pretty dominant position.  I was working towards a transcendence victory (making a mind flower), and the AI finished one a few turns before I did.

After the mind flower is completed, how do you win?   The victory page seems to indicate that I just wait... is the enemy on a different timer?   If I have a lot of mind stems will I reach the end faster than the AI?   It's not clear how they function.

Can I destroy the enemies mind flower to stall their progress?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The victory page seems to indicate that I just wait... is the enemy on a different timer?

Exactly that. The initial time span can be shortened by building the **Xeno Sanctuary** and the **Mind Stem** in your cities.

Assuming two players finish the **Mind Flower** the same turn, the player with more cities having a **Xeno Sanctuary** and a **Mind Stem** will essentially win (due to faster point generation).

You can delay a *Transcendence Victory* by destroying those buildings/raiding the cities with them.

If you'd like to cut-off some other player's progress, you'll have to attack and destroy the **Mind Flower**.

Just keep in mind that this victory condition [might be slightly bugged according to Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/2kzh8x/be_destroyed_her_mind_flower_the_ai_still_won_as/).

Comment: Thanks! I found that same reddit thread while I was waiting, and it looks like there's a lot of screwy things with that mode.  Should have kept my military going instead!

Comment: Also, if you take over the opponent city that hosts their Mind Flower it can stop their progress. (Though that progress can be resumed at the the time they recover the city, from the point where it stopped.)

Answer (score 0):

As I've just learned, it is very bugged. I not only annexed the city that built the mind flower, but eliminated the player entirely. That defeated player won with a transcendence victory about 20 turns later...